# Jar file not Finding Image Directory

Tags: java, image, jar, icons, embedded-resource

I'm trying to launch a JAR file that has images that are used in the program. However it can't find them so the labels go blank. How do I go about fixing this?

Do I need all of the images in the same folder of the JAR folder and go into my code and edit the directory or would that not work?

**Edit**,  Images obtained thusly:

```
hex19.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/hexHouse.png")); //How the images are used.
```

Comment: How are you trying to load the images?  Where are the images stored?  Are the stored on the file system or the bundled with the Jar?

Comment: Please show your code where you try to get the images. Hopefully you're not trying to access them as files but rather as resources.

Comment: hex19.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/hexHouse.png")); //How the images are used. You mentioned using them as resources? What do you mean by that?

Comment: Don't try to show code in comments but rather as an edit to your original post, something that I have taken the liberty of doing for you above.

Comment: Using `src` in a resource location is always a harbinger of trouble. However you build your JAR file, the `src` directory will not be there.  If you are using Ant, the build process will compile your java files to a staging area, typically `classes` or `build/classes`. Then, a `<copy>` task will copy all your non-Java resources to the same location. Then, a `<jar>` task will create the JAR file. But `src` and `classes` and `build\classes` will not appear in the JAR file at all. Other build techniques do roughly the equivalent. The answer assumes that the resource is alongside the class.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you are in fact trying to get the images as files, and files do not exist inside pf jars. Instead you must get the images as resources.

i.e.,

```
  BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("imageStreamLocation.png"));
  ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
  hex19.setIcon(icon);
```

The key will be using the correct image stream location. This should be a relative path to the "file" but relative to the location of the jar's class files.

Comment: That makes sense! I don't know why I didn't do that in the first place. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user1920076: you and all the rest of us who have to stumble over this problem. Myself and everyone else know about this problem because we have been in precisely your same shoes when first learning to create jar files.